# COUNT() comments each time vs cache in count_comments column vs use another type of cache

Tags: mysql, caching, count

I have a common doubt.

Guess I am creating a social network or blog with posts, and each post has comments.

If I want to paginate and filter a lists of posts and show the amount of comments of each post

Should I add a count_comments column to my posts table (like WP does) and cache the amount of comments there (i.e. every time someone comments add 1 if someone deletes a comment sub 1 to the count_comments column)

Should I perform a SUBSELECT to COUNT the amount of comments every time and then cache the result with another form or caching

Or what do you recommend?

Comment: It all depends on the amount of data you want to process. This question cannot be answered because it's actually too broad. I'd not even go with MySQL if you ask for a recommendation and I'd avoid subselects as much as possible (subselects are ran on every row, they are so slow, you can deadlock several tables easily).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short words: Both will work, and both variants have their advantages and disadvantages.

You'll almost certainly will have arguments for both ways.

If you need the comment count frequently, and it takes alot of system/application ressources to get that value with a simple sql statement (p.e. sorting by that value could be a pain), storing the value in a field like WordPress does is a way to do it.

If you don't need the comment count frequently, and/or it doesn't take alot of ressources to get the values (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourcommenttable WHERE yourpostid = whatever` shouldn't be too tough for most systems), you would possibly benefit more while avoiding the issues keeping the value in sync with the actual comments in the posts.

Comment: I need to show the most popular posts (those with more comments)

Trying the COUNT approach I had to use a SUBSELECT in the ORDER BY to achieve that

The count subquery is simple, it only requires a comments.post_id = posts.id WHERE condition.

And on the other hand I need the count in every view (posts list and details)

So I am still not sure what is the best way to go

Comment: Then go for the extra field, thats why i mentioned sorting in my answer. But again, both ways are valid.

Answer (score 0):

definitely cache them using triggers, safe and efficient for the future. But keep in mind that you dont need the count for pagination, maybe only just for displaying the count in some stats

Comment: If I use trigger my database wouldn't be portable and the app logic would be divided, could I also use the event system with the framework I'm working on (Laravel) to add or subtract to the count column?

Comment: I think you could, but then it is probably less reliable